# Currently in American region when tried changing to SEA region a new profile was asked to be required

Tags: starcraft-2

To be able to add my friend in Starcraft 2 who is in SEA region I too have to be in SEA region I presume.
When I tried switching to SEA region it required me to enter my character name.
My question is if i enter my character name will I still me able to have my levels and acheivements still with me?

Comment: Only going by what I saw when I accidentally opened SC2 with the US region selected. I entered a new character name and pretty much had a clean game. No achievements, no progress. When I switched back to EU, everything was back and still intact. Not sure of anything else regarding this matter.

Answer (score 2):

Achievements and experience are specific to your region, so when you (essentially) make a new account on SEA, the account will be empty.

The creation process on SEA will be as if you just bought the game and are entering your battlenet username for the first time.